# Categorize a random color into one of the primary colors Windows Phone

Tags: c#, colors, windows-phone-8

I am trying to create a method that accepts a random color value then check which primary colors it's closest to.

[image]

I imagine I have to compare its RGB value and see where it falls within the range of those primary colors and then set it as Red, or Yellow or Blue etc.

What is the best way of doing this? Thanks

**EDIT**
This question is marked as duplicate but I checked the other answer of the said duplicate question but it doesn't offer the answer I am after.

using the formula

```
d = sqrt((r2-r1)^2 + (g2-g1)^2 + (b2-b1)^2)
```

sometimes produce the same value for different colors. For instance take an input color of `R170 : G0 : B255`.  The distances from both white `R255 : G255 : B255` and red `R255 : G0 : B0` produce (int)269 using the formula. So which color is closer, red or white? I removed black and white from the list but the problem still occurs for some other colors.

I am comparing with several colors  i.e:  black, white, red, lime. blue, yellow, cyan. magenta and gray as listed in the RGB color table here rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm

Comment: I would treat it as a vector and find the magnitude from each polar (0,1,0), (1,0,0), (0,0,1), (See [Link](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/301/lectures/node28.html))

Comment: (Above should be 255's instead of 1's)

Comment: good suggestion.. lets see if I can code something along this idea.

Comment: I've added in pseudo if it will help

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an IDE infront of me but here's my comment in pseudo (Can update later if necessary)

```
var closestColor

Get vector magnitude of( myR + 255, myG, myB)
set closestColor to Red

Get vector magnitude of( myR , myG+ 255, myB)
If(Green is closer than red)
 set closestColor to Green

Get vector magnitude of( myR , myG, myB + 255)
If(Blue is closer than closestColor)
 set closestColor to Blue

Return closest color
```

**Update**

I did a quick linq example with extension

```
    public static double VectorMagnitude(this Color c, Color otherC)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(((int)(c.R + otherC.R))^2 + 
            ((int)(c.G + otherC.G))^2 + 
            ((int)(c.B + otherC.B))^2); 
    }

    private static List<Color> Colors()
    {
        return new List<Color>()
        {
            Color.Red,
            Color.Blue,
            Color.FromArgb(0,255,0)
        };
    }

 var l = Colors().OrderBy(x => x.VectorMagnitude(
                Color.FromArgb(255, R, G, B))).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Tested this but I found that since it's based on average distance, two different colors might give similar 'closeness'. For instance input color `R170 : G0 : B255` distance from both white ` R255 : G255 : B255` and red `R 255 : G0 : B0` produce (int)269 using the formula

Comment: your not after the distance from white, your after the distance from solid red/blue/green

Comment: Right. But what if I want to compare to other 'basic' colors as well? My list contains, black, white, red, lime. blue, yellow, cyan. magenta and gray as listed in the RGB color table here http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm

Comment: Putra, in your example, it should return closest to blue

Comment: I think you are right, the problem I was facing was when adding the distance value as dictionary key which sometimes produce similar values. But I wonder what if two colors have the closest distance? Like in my example, what if there are no closest value besides the two?

Comment: you have a choice, either return one of them or return the color i.e red/green = (255,255,0)

Comment: @PutraKg - I've updated with a bit of a linq example that will find the closest color from a list (green doesn't exist apparently) and then return it (if theres any equal distance, the first is returned)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a real comparison between two colors you shouldn't use the RGB color space.
It's not suited for color calculations.

Your best bet is to convert it to LAB color space. [LAB space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space)

To achieve this you need to convert the RGB to XYZ values and then convert these to LAB. You can find the calculations for this on this website: [Bruce Lindbloom](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/)

When you have the LAB colors you can choose a difference formula. The easiest is the CIE74, but if you want the most accurate results you need to use the CIEDE2000. [Difference Formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference)

I've used these formulas for the last 5 months on a project I worked on, so if you need any help just let me know.